# I'm curious on methods of encrypting files using C++

Tags: encryption, 3des

I'm making a personal security tool in C++ and was curious how I would go about encrypting files in C++. If anyone has a method that would be great, and more specifically I was interested in 3DES encryption.

Comment: Welcome to crypto.stackexchange - This is a programming question, and programming questions are off-topic here even if they are about using cryptography. Programming questions belong on stackoverflow. I can migrate this to stackoverflow for you.

Answer (score 3):

3DES is an [old](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/146710/is-the-3des-algorithm-secure) and [slow](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/26233/is-des-slow-in-hardware-or-only-in-software) cipher.
In 2019, it is probably a bad idea to build new applications based on this algorithm.

Choosing a cipher, is not the only thing that matter in cryptography. 
You need a [mode of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) like CBC or GCM to specify how to combine encryption function on long messages.
If you don't use [AEAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption) modes, you probably need a MAC construction to protect ciphertexts from malleability.

Choosing all theses things in a secure way is difficult.
That's why, your best option is to use a library that provide a secure API for encryption.
[Libsodium](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium) is a mature example of such library and the `crypto_secretbox_*` functions are probably what you need.
They are based on [XSalsa20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salsa20)+[Poly1305](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poly1305) construction.

Comment: That's awesome, thanks for the info, I'll check it out.