# Why do we use multiple rounds of encryption?

Tags: encryption, algorithm-design, symmetric, des

I understand that DES and AES use multiple rounds of encryption to secure the cipher text output, what is the real reason this is carried out?

Is there a certain point performing multiple rounds becomes pointless not relating to security; as of course performance becomes an issue at some point?

Do all encryption algorithms require multiple rounds in order to make them secure?

Comment: Related: [Why does SHA-1 have 80 rounds?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/14971/why-does-sha-1-have-80-rounds/14972#14972)

Comment: For the same reason that cards are shuffled multiple times.

Comment: Related: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2648/how-were-the-number-of-rounds-for-different-key-sizes-of-aes-selected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the same scheme multiple times will allow for efficient crypto-analysis. If the cipher cannot be analysed then this will be considered detrimental to security. The cipher itself doesn't need to be hard; it just must be hard to reverse without the key. The rounds themselves do not provide enough confusion to be considered a full cipher themselves.

Having rounds where the same scheme is repeated allows for efficient implementation, making the code size much smaller and easier to protect against side channel attacks.

---

Yes, the required number of rounds can be limited to the best attack available. Generally any cipher with rounds will have successful (if theoretical) attacks over a number of rounds. The problem is that you don't know which attacks will be devised in the future.

So in the end some kind of margin is in order; there is a *non-trivial* balance between future proofing an algorithm and performance. To what number of rounds an algorithm is tweaked is often subject to discussion.

Having at least 3 "spare rounds" is probably advised. That doesn't take into account the complexity of each round (Threefish is used with 80 lightweight rounds while AES uses a minimum of 10, more complex rounds). You'd expect more "spare rounds" when a lot of rounds are required in the first place.

---

Generally block ciphers will use rounds, but stream ciphers may use different ways of generating a key stream. Asymmetric encryption such as RSA generally doesn't use rounds at all.

It's certainly not a theoretical security requirement to use rounds.